# Variable containing an operator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, operators

I'm trying to make a change to a variable using a custom operator (I will explain it clearlier now).
I have an array of numbers, and I have to `reduce()` it. First 2 numbers will be added, then in the second reducing they will be substracted, then multiplied, divided and exponentiated. Basically:

```
[1,2,3,4,5] -> 0
1+2=3
3-3=0
0*4=0
0/5=0 -> 0
```

So I saw an implementation like this:

```
f => f.reduce((a,b,c) => [a + b, a - b, a * b, a / b, a ** b][c % 5])
```

And wondered, can I make an array of operators in some way, and implement it like this?

```
f => f.reduce((a,b,c) => a [+,-,*,/,**][c%5] b)
```

Clearly this syntax is incorrect, but in the terms of an idea, does something like this exist?

Comment: Since operators aren't first class objects, no, that's not really possible unfortunately (ignoring `eval`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)** method

```js
var f = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(
  f.reduce((a, b, c) => eval(a + ['+', '-', '*', '/'][c-1] + b))
);
```

---

Also I don't prefer to use **[`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)**, refer : [Don't use eval needlessly!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don't_use_eval_needlessly!)

---

**UPDATE :**
Also as ***@NinaScholz*** said, you can reduce the code by using string instead of string array. Both string and array have same effect in this case.

```js
var f = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(
  f.reduce((a, b, c) => eval(a + '+-*/'[c - 1] + b))
);
```

Comment: Well, it seems to be the best answer until now.. Thanks.

Comment: you could shorten it to `f.reduce((a, b, c) => eval(a + '+-*/'[c-1] + b))`

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```js
var add = function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  },
  sub = function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  },
  mul = function(a, b) {
    return a * b;
  },
  div = function(a, b) {
    return a / b;
  };
var operations = [add, sub, mul, div];

var output = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce(function(p, c, i) {
  return operations[i - 1](p, c)
});

console.log(output);
```

You can add more functions (custom operators) and decide the order of operations.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array for the operators.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    op = [
        (a, b) => a + b,
        (a, b) => a - b,
        (a, b) => a * b,
        (a, b) => a / b,
    ];

console.log(array.reduce((r, a, i) => op[(i - 1) % 4](r, a)));
```

Comment: This is not an array of operators, this is an array of functions (represented in lambda expression form). This is not exactly what I need (I need the code to be as short as possible)